# Antd Segmented: Set tabindex=-1 to the internal Input component

Tags: javascript, antd, tabindex

I'm using the `Segmented` component by Ant Design. My application has some component like this:

```js
...

import EmployeeCard from './EmployeeCard';
import ContractorCard from './ContractorCard';


function MyComponent() {

  const [cardType, setCardType] = useState('Employee');

  ...
  
  function changeCard(value) {
    setCardType(value);
  }
  
  return (
  
    ...
    
    <Segmented
      options={['Employee', 'Contractor']}
      onChange={changeCard)
      value={cardType}
      tabIndex={-1}
    />
    {cardType === 'Employee'
      ? <EmployeeCard />
      : <ContractorCard />
    }
    
    ...
  );
}
```

The `EmployeeCard` and `ContractorCard` have some input components in them that I want to be part of the overall tab flow on the page. However, I don't want the `Segmented` buttons themselves to be part of it. I set `tabIndex={-1}` on the `Segmented` component in order to take it out of the tab-flow, but apparently, internally, that component includes an `Input` component, which still has the default `tabIndex={0}`. I cannot figure out how to reach that component in order to set its tab index to -1.